# Center align my content with css

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I did little boxes on my website to shortly describe our activity, The text is that the same length for all the boxes so I am trying to center the text in the middle of the box with my css. I tried display:table-cell, vertical-align:center, but it doesn't work.
Did someone has an idea about what I can do?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you please add your code?.

Comment: There are many problems with this post. **a)** We don't know what your exact problem is. **b)** there are no screenshots/code examples of the problem. **c)** the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

In css,

```
.text-center {
    text-align : center;
}
```

Add a class `.text-center` to you div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: table;` to the text container and

```
display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
```

to your text span/h1/p

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: table;
  background: blue;
}
h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

You need to add your code and be very specific about the question next time.